# How can I allow ajaxterm to connect to foreign hosts?

Tags: ssh

I have installed ajaxterm from the repo and put it behind nginx. It works fine. However, it only allows to log in to the server it's running on.

**How do I allow users to connect to an arbitrary host of their choice?** Preferably, I'd like to limit that choice to a list of pre-approved hosts but just allowing any host would be good enough. I'd also like to avoid giving everyone shell access to the gateway server that ajaxterm is running on.

Possible? [ServerDo](https://ssh.serverdo.in/) seems to have it running like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There's a patched copy of AjaxTerm for this exact use-case](https://github.com/nats/ajaxterm).